# What does the harpoon do? How to use it?

Tags: road-redemption

I've picked up the harpoon firearm a few times now, and I can't figure out what it's for.

- Shooting an enemy rider with it doesn't appear to do much but briefly stun them as with a melee attack, and with no discernible damage.
- Shooting the ground or an object tethers me to it with a wire, but this doesn't have any effect that I can figure out either.  Once I drive past my harpoon the wire just extends out behind me, as seen (sort of) in the image below.

What do I use the harpoon for?

[image: Road Redemption Harpoon]

Comment: Try firing at the wall / level when you are going around a turn, it can enable you to boost around a turn at a higher speed than normal, or keep yourself from flying off the edge

Comment: @Dpeif sounds good to me, feel free to post as an answer!